# Can I change the data displayed on hovering over a bubble chart in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, hover, salesforce, visualforce, bubble-chart

Can I hover over the bubbles in a bubble chart and display different data instead of the data points (x and y axis data)?

[Picture of current bubble chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zJzR.png)

[Rep names in a single line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcvTe.png)

[Rep names list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcZHq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with `tooltip.pointFormat` or `tooltip.pointFormatter()` if you want to display some other information conditionally. For points of a given series, you can enter not only basic information such as x, y, z, name, and some default ones but also custom ones:

```js
tooltip: {
  //pointFormat: '<div>{point.custom}</div>',
  pointFormatter: function() {
    const point = this;
    return point.custom ? point.custom : 'z: '+point.z;
  }
},
series: [{
  data: [{
    x: 2,
    y: 4,
    z: 8,
    custom: 'Custom tooltip info'
    }]
}]
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vdf9rnu6/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.data

Comment: Thank you! This helped. We are able to customise the data displayed but it appears in a single line (names of reps) Is there a way I can format the string to display them one below the other? (Added image in question)

Comment: You can just add HTML tags like <br/> to add other names to next lines: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rogp3qcx/

Comment: Can we remove 'Series 1' displayed and add the x and y axis data points on top of the rep names? (In 'rep names list' image) Also, can we limit the number of values displayed on hover and add a view more option?